How can I pad an element in <pre> and retain tab size?
I'm trying to add padding to (autogenerated) lines of code, with indefinitely many <span>s inside <pre><code>. I select the each direct child of <code> with
pre code > span {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

but when rendered, the padding eats away at the width of a tab character, as if the tab began rendering at the beginning of the element, including the padding. This occurs on both Chrome and Firefox.
This should illustrate my situation:


<pre><code><span>hello</span>
<span>  <span>there</span></span></code></pre>

<style>
    :root {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        tab-size: 4;
    }
    pre code > span {
        background-color: green;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
    }
</style>



Notice that the columnar space between "hello" and "there" is about 1.75, not 4. If the padding unit is switched to ch, the tab is exactly that many characters less wide. Tab characters after the first aren't affected.
I can't change the structure of the markup.
The goal (the reason I put padding on <span>, not <code>) is to make the background color take up the entirety of the line, so that there isn't a gap when the entire line is colored differently (for a diff, for example): padding on the code element, correct tab width versus padding on each child span, bad tab width. If there were a "negative padding" I think that would work.
The closest similar issue I could find introduced nothing for me and isn't related to tab width. I don't believe text-indent helps as it only seems to have an effect when applied to <pre>.
